# Parse Data with links to youtube or similar

Tags: parse-platform

Hi Guys has anyone implemented youtube links into Parse data??

I am currently trying to do this as I am doing a mobile app that may need videos...?

Where would i put the code, as in what category of data?

Comment: If it's just links, you can just use a string that holds the URL.

Comment: Would that embed them into my app?

Comment: I am trying to embed them into the app Vlad...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding embedding, if you're working on Android:

> The [YouTube Android Player
>   API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) enables
>   you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android
>   applications. The API defines methods for loading and playing YouTube
>   videos (and playlists) and for customizing and controlling the video
>   playback experience.

For iOS, there's also a [helper library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

I don't know what the connection to Parse is, but if you want to control what videos there are from the server, then store whatever URL or identifier the Player API requires you to have in order to play them on the client.